# SearchKit: return a value from one field based on the value in another?

Tags: searchkit, directory

I am building a Membership Directory using SearchKit and FormBuilder.
The Directory includes details of statutory license to practice (regulator + licence number, combined in SearchKit as a string) (values stored in two custom fields of the Individual Contact record).
I want to hide these details if the Individual is also marked Practice Status "Retired" (also stored in the Individual Contact Record).
How can one construct a SearchKit query (or perhaps alternatively conditionally change the combined field value, which is passed to the public Form) to hide the combined value if the Practice Status = "Retired"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are on CiviCRM >= 5.47.x, you can use smarty conditions in the rewrite section of the field on display searches.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

the expression would be something like below

```
{if "[Contact.Details_ccc.Practice_Status]” neq “Retired”}[CONCAT_WS_COMBINED_TEXT_REG_LIC_NUMBER]{else}{/if}
```

**Note**: Replace the field name in the square brackets([]) with actual names.

HTH

Pradeep
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TzzqY.png

Comment: Thanks Pradeep! Will give it a go and mark "answered" if it works!

Comment: The rewrite field seems not to interpret that code correctly, and I get just the text of the code appearing on the form (though it does pick up the specified field). This is what I have in the rewrite field:  {if "[Membership_Contact_contact_id_01.Details_ccc.Registration_status:label]” neq “Retired”}[CONCAT_WS_Membership_Contact_contact_id_01_Details_ccc_Practise_Licensing_Authority_Membership_Contact_contact_id_01_Details_ccc_Practise_license_number]{else}{/if}.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: probably mis-speaking but you have :label in the above - shouldn't that be :value?

Comment: @petednz I have tried replacing :label with :value and the changed behaviour is odd. With :label, the text of the expression is returned (albeit with the contents for the field I am manipulating inserted into the expression). With :value; the entire result of the query is blank. Logically (I think), if SK did not recognise the expression as code, it should be agnostic about :label and :value!

Comment: @petednz: I have found the problem I think. Pradeep did say that Civi 5.47 was needed to use this Smarty expression, and I suspect that Smarty is not implemented for this usage in 5.46 (which is the version we are on). I should read more carefully! Not sure if there is an alternative construction of the expression I could use now, or if we need to upgrade!

Comment: Yes, Civi should be on 5.47 to use smarty conditioning. It is a best practice to use ':name' for checks since this won't change